Poker strategy with blind betting
I came across a version of Texas hold ‘em poker where if you’re blind, your chip value is doubled at betting time (ie. to call 10, you only put in 5). You can look at your cards at any time, at which time chip value for your bets return to normal, but you don’t change the chips already put into the pot.
For example, Alice is blind, Bob is not. Alice bets 5. Bob raises to 20. Alice checks cards and calls with 10 (5*2 for initial bet + 10 post-looking).
What’s strategy here? My intuition is that one wants to look if they are out of position, stay blind in position, and non-blind wants to bet 25%-50% of blind’s stack size, but I’m unable to formalize a general betting theory.

My guess would be that you stay blind, don't raise, and look if there's exactly one other person left in - either that or stay blind (I don't think it matters.)  The intuition is that, with $n$ players, your odds of winning are $1/n$, and by not raising, you are betting proportionally to $1/(2n)$.  Your odds of winning per $ bet are 2x that of the other players, and, since it's a zero-sum game, that puts you ahead.  My other intuitive strategy is to stay blind until half the players are left, then look; the intuition is that you might be in the half that should be out.

@jbowman In practice it becomes $n=2$ very quickly (almost always pre-flop). My notes were exclusively for this case. I agree with your notes for $n>2$
